# Need to remove the plan value for multiple condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to remove the plan options for the same multiple value occurrence

test.xml

```
<p base="OptionDesc"></p>
```

Input XML value having:

```
<PlanMaps>
    <PlanMap>
        <PlanCode>10049</PlanCode>
        <Strategy>F</Strategy>
        <OptionDesc>Option 2424809</OptionDesc>
    </PlanMap>
    <PlanMap>
        <PlanCode>10049</PlanCode>
        <Strategy>F</Strategy>
        <OptionDesc>Option 2424796</OptionDesc>
    </PlanMap>
    <PlanMap>
        <PlanCode>10049</PlanCode>
        <Strategy>F</Strategy>
        <OptionDesc>Option 2414596</OptionDesc>
    </PlanMap>
    <PlanMap>
        <PlanCode>30019</PlanCode>
        <Strategy>V</Strategy>
        <OptionDesc>Option 2414600</OptionDesc>
    </PlanMap>
  </PlanMaps>
```

XSL I have tried:

```
<xsl:template match="PlanMaps">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('../../../../test.xml')"/>
   </xsl:template>  
   
<xsl:template match="p[@base='OptionDesc'][parent::entry/@outputclass='plans']">
    <p base="OptionDesc">
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="PlanMaps/PlanMap/OptionDesc"/>    
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Expectation of result when the `Strategy` value is "F" and when `PlanCode` value (10049) is same for multiple occurrence(two or more), then result should be empty like below

```
<p base="OptionDesc"></p>
<p base="OptionDesc">(Option 2414600)</p>
```

Here I need the XSL without mentioning the value of plancode in XSL.

Comment: So that `test.xml` has a single `p base="OptionDesc"` element?

Comment: Yes @MartinHonnen

Comment: But what is it needed for then? It seems you can just process the primary input and group and process and map each group to a `p base="OptionDesc"` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just need to process the primary input:

```
  <xsl:template match="PlanMaps">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="PlanMap" group-by="concat(PlanCode, '|',  Strategy = 'F')">
          <p base="OptionDesc">
              <xsl:value-of select="concat('(', OptionDesc, ')')[not(current-group()[2] and current-group()/Strategy = 'F')]"/>
          </p>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVrN/1